# Angular&Django: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: django, angular, cors, xmlhttprequest

I'm learning how to develop a website using Angular and Django. I got this error from my Angular localhost:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/' from origin 
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request 
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In django's settings.py I have installed a custom **users** app, **rest_framework** and **corsheaders** app
Besides that, I have included this config:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

I've stacked the middleware in this way:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', #CORS middleware
    'users.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', #custom middleware for jwt
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I've got no CORS errors with login and register requests from my angular app but the problem appeared when I used a middleware to check if a jwt header had been supplied (and test if it was valid or if it had expired). I added that middleware to settings.py file and that request worked fine in Postman so I tried to implement it from Angular.

This is the method:

```
validateToken(): Observable<boolean> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/user/`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'jwt',
      localStorage.getItem('token') || ''
    );
    return this.http
      .get<AuthResponse>(url, {
        headers,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((resp) => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', resp.jwt);
          this._user = resp.user;
          return resp.ok;
        }),
        catchError((err) => of(false))
      );
```

However, I'm getting the error I showed before. Have any of you gone through this same problem with Angular and Django before and know how it could be solved?

PS: I've tried to install 'Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Chrome extension but when I used it I still got this error:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' 
 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
 It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

There you have a screenshot of preflight request and response from browser's network tab:

[image: preflight request headers]

[image: preflight response headers 1]

[image: preflight response headers 2]

Comment: Please show how you've stacked your middleware. Your CORS middleware should appear before any authentication middleware, because preflight requests are never authenticated.

Comment: I changed the order as you said but it continues not working

Comment: I believe the CORS middleware should be at the very top, even before the security middleware. However, you shouldn't allow all origins with credentials; that's very insecure!

Comment: I put CORS middleware on top but the problem still persists. I had configured that only my angular origin could make requests but it didn't work either

Comment: You should add a screenshot of your browser's Network tab showing the preflight request and response.

Comment: I've just added it

Comment: Not good enough. You need to show the request and response headers.

Comment: Okay, I've added them

Comment: You're using a `jwt` request header, but your server needs to explicitly allow it (by listing it in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header).

Comment: Thank you so much, al last it worked when I added `jwt` header to the `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-HEADERS` list in `settings.py`. I should have checked the browser's network tab beforehand

Answer (score -1):

On your headers variable you need to set a pair of property:value containing the missing access control property:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
```

Comment: I'd already tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, but this is exactly why this error is coming, so it's a clue for solving it.